# Does setting DNT make one a target to extra tracking?

Tags: fingerprinting, tracking

Does adding the "Do Not Track" (DNT) to HTTP headers make one a target for extra tracking, such as in-depth [browser fingerprinting](https://panopticlick.eff.org)?

Comment: As far as I know, the header is pretty much ignored by most websites

Comment: You may have your tinfoil on too tight. I would hazard that the kind of people who would say "we ought to track people who don't want to be tracked" are already tracking everyone as well as they can.

Comment: @notstoreboughtdirt There's got to be a scientific way of testing this, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say no.

This is from Wiki:

> "There are no legal or technological requirements for its use, when
>   it's enabled by default on browsers. As such, websites and advertisers
>   may either honour the request, or completely ignore it in cases where
>   it's automatically set".

So if an organisation wanted to track you and DNT was set, they could just ignore it and carry on and track you anyway. Any respectable organisation that observed DNT would probably not engage in such behaviour.

Comment: `Any respectable organisation` We have so many *not* respecatble organizations on this planet...